# EXCEL how to move from colon n to column (n-1) no negatif

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have value like this the empty is full of zero

```
   1 2 3 4 5
     1 2 3 2
       4 5 7
         2 5
           1
```

I would like to have them like this

```
    1 2 3 4 5
    1 2 3 2
    4 5 7
    2 5 
    1
```

I thought about using the index function, the vlookup but it  doesn't work.I tried the match function too but I have a #NA :( . 
I am using index function right now and it's working but I want to know if there is a faster way because I have big file.
On the row it's ok but for the column it is another story;

Can someone help me please?

Comment: While empty cells in above table are supposed to be full of zeros, what if you have a 0 in the valid list of numbers e.g. 1 2 3 0 5, do you want to include it or exclude it?

Comment: I will want to include it.

Comment: If you don't know already, numbers are right aligned. Text is left aligned. To accomplish this you can make your numbers text, or you can left justify your numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your data is in Cells A1:E5 then say in A10 put the following formula and drag it down below and across until you get the desired list as expected.

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($A$1:$E$5,ROW(1:1),COLUMN()-COLUMN($A$10)+ROW(1:1))),"",INDEX($A$1:$E$5,ROW(1:1),COLUMN()-COLUMN($A$10)+ROW(1:1)))
```

Note that in whichever cell you start the formula you should put the Column($Column$Row) in the formula e.g. COLUMN($A$10) in this case in the above formula because I am starting in Cell A10. If you miss this step and copy the above formula as-is elsewhere it will not give intended results.

Assumption is that as you increase the rows, the number of leading zeros increases sequentially i.e. starting first row it's 0 then 1 2 3 4 etc. So it's INDEX function returning (1,1)(1,2)(1,3)..in first row then (2,2)(2,3)..in second row, (3,3)(3,4)..in third and so on, based on manipulation or ROW() & COLUMN() functions.

[image]